# Scala practices: lists and case classes

Tags: scala, list, case-class

I've just started using Scala/Spark and having come from a Java background and I'm still trying to wrap my head around the concept of immutability and other best practices of Scala.

This is a very small segment of code from a larger program:
intersections is RDD(Key, (String, String))
obs is (Key, (String, String))
Data is just a case class I've defined above.

```
val intersections = map1 join map2
var listOfDatas = List[Data]()
intersections take NumOutputs foreach (obs => {
  listOfDatas ::= ParseInformation(obs._1.key, obs._2._1, obs._2._2)
})

listOfDatas foreach println
```

This code works and does what I need it to do, but I was wondering if there was a better way of making this happen. I'm using a variable list and rewriting it with a new list every single time I iterate, and I'm sure there has to be a better way to create an immutable list that's populated with the results of the ParseInformation method call. Also, I remember reading somewhere that instead of accessing the tuple values directly, the way I have done, you should use case classes within functions (as partial functions I think?) to improve readability.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work locally, but only because you are `take`ing locally. It will not work once distributed as the `listOfDatas` is passed to each worker as a copy.  The better way of doing this IMO is:

```
val processedData = intersections map{case (key, (item1, item2)) => {
  ParseInfo(key, item1, item2)
}}

processedData foreach println
```

A note for a new to functional dev: If all you are trying to do is transform data in an iterable (`List`), forget `foreach`. Use `map` instead, which runs your transformation on each item and spits out a new iterable of the results.

Answer (score 1):

What's the type of `intersections`?  It looks like you can replace `foreach` with `map`:

```
val listOfDatas: List[Data] =
  intersections take NumOutputs map (obs => {
    ParseInformation(obs._1.key, obs._2._1, obs._2._2)
  })
```

Comment: Ooh, Justin Pihony's answer is better than mine.